# Python: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement using jupyter and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to make a function to pass parameters and return queries in jupyter but it returns the following error "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement".

For now I made the connection using:

```
import mysql.connector as connection
import pandas as pd

db = connection.connect (parameters of connection)
```

My function has to pass 3 parameters and return the dataframe and its queries according to these parameters, so i'm doing:

```
    def param (id, id_user, date):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    if (id == '' or None) and (id_user == '' or None) and (date == '' or None):
        query = 'select * from database'
        df = pd.read_sql(query, db)
    elif (id_user == '' or None) and (date == '' or None):
        query = 'select * from database where id = %s'
        df = pd.read_sql(query, db, params = id)
    else:
        print(':(')
    return df
```

Then the error appears when i execute:

```
param (18, '', '')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a tuple as the value for `params`:

```py
query = 'select * from database where id = %s'
df = pd.read_sql(query, db, params = (id,))  # change is here
```

In your current code, you are passing a single variable `id` directly, but most likely it is expecting a tuple.

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684970/execution-failed-on-sql-select-name-from-sqlite-master-where-type-table-and-n